# Where do these extra query results come from?

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, slim

I am querying a postgres database through a php/slim api. The query itself works fine, but I get extra results which I cannot explain.

The goal is to build an API for an update tool. The database holds multiple dataset for every client and every user.

The relevant table looks like this:

[image]

Below is the php function which executes the query i need

```
function checkVersion($version,$uuid ) {
    $version = strval($version);
    try {
        $pdo = new PDO('pgsql:host=localhost;port=5432;dbname=update;user=postgres;password=12345');
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM client where version = ? and uuid = ?;";
        $prepStm = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $prepStm->execute(array($version,$uuid));
        $flawless = $prepStm->execute(array($version, $uuid)); // result as bool for some other evaluations
        $queryResult = $prepStm->fetch();
        $results = array(
            "flawless"    => $flawless,
            "queryResult" => $queryResult
        );
        error_log(__LINE__.' '.json_encode($results)); // debugging log
        return $results;
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex) {
        error_log(__LINE__.' '.$ex);
        return $ex;
    }
};
```

And this is the logged result

```
"queryResult":{"id":1,"0":1,"uuid":26801208922265,"1":26801208922265,"version":"1.1.0","2":"1.1.0","lastupdate":"01.07.2019","3":"01.07.2019","kunde":1,"4":1}
```

The expected results such as "id", "uuid" and so on are there, **but** where do the extra records "0", "1" "2" "3" "4" come from? Whats even more weird is that they have the exact same values as the expected results.

What am I missing here? Does this maybe happen because I execute the statement two consecutive times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the extra values because the default fetch mode for [`PDOStatement::fetch`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) is `PDO::FETCH_BOTH`, which fetches the data indexed by both column name and number. From the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php):

> PDO::FETCH_BOTH (default): returns an array indexed by both column name and 0-indexed column number as returned in your result set

If you only want one set of values (e.g. the associative keys), call `fetch` with the `fetch_style` parameter `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` i.e.

```
$queryResult = $prepStm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

In terms of executing the query twice, there is no need to do that (just use the line which assigns the result to `$flawless`) but since it's a `SELECT` the only real effect will be to slow your code down.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, ```->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)``` works like a charm. Im note quite sure on the double execution part, i need both the acutal result and the true/false response when omitting the ```->fetch()``` part. how can i get both with just one line?

Comment: @jdoe no matter whether you assign the result of the `execute` or not, the query still gets executed. So just having a line `$flawless = $prepStm->execute(array($version, $uuid));` will execute the query and give you the true/false response. Trust me! :)

Comment: I am very sorry, i dont really understand how to accomplish this, could you show me an code example?

Comment: @jdoe all you have to do is remove this line: `$prepStm->execute(array($version,$uuid));` from your code. It will still work just fine.

Answer (score -2):

You can try:

```
while($arr=$prepStm->fetch()){  
    print_r($arr);  
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer - how does this code solve the given question?